# How similar are the implementations of hibernate and nhibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, hibernate

How similar are the implementations of hibernate and nhibernate?

i.e. if I am comfortable with nhibernate, will hibernate be a very easy transition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used Hibernate a lot and read up on NHibernate, and as far as the basics go, they appear very similar.

- Mapping files (.hbm.xml) are used in both Hibernate and NHibernate, and appear almost identical for simple configurations (except for XML namespaces).
- While NHibernate configuration isn't done in a hibernate.properties file like in Hibernate, the keys used are the same.
- The same basic interfaces are used between Hibernate and NHibernate, but they just have an 'I' at the beginning in .NET (SessionFactory vs. ISessionFactory).
- Most of the basic methods have the same name in NHibernate, but the .NET methods are capitalized unlike in Java (`session.Save(user)` vs. `session.save(user)`).